# Press multiple keys at once to get my character to move diagonally

Tags: python, events, pygame, keyboard-events

The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to make my character move diagonally on screen when a user presses either the K_UP key and K_RIGHT key or the K_UP key and K_DOWN key, etc. Here is my code for character movement (event handling):

```
1. #Event Handling
2. for event in pygame.event.get():
3.     if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
4.         sys.exit()
5.     elif (event.type == KEYDOWN):
6.         if ((event.key == K_ESCAPE)
7.             or (event.key == K_q)):
8.             sys.exit()
9.         if (event.key == K_UP):
10.            self.char_y = self.char_y - 10
11.        if (event.key == K_DOWN):
12.            self.char_y = self.char_y + 10
13.        if (event.key == K_RIGHT):
14.            self.char_x = self.char_x + 10
15.        if (event.key == K_LEFT):
16.            self.char_x = self.char_x - 10
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: that long chain of `if`s could perhaps be better expressed as a mapping: `event_dict = {K_ESCAPE: sys.exit, K_UP: lambda: setattr(self, 'char_y', self.char_y-10)}` etc, followed by `event_dict[event.key]()`

Comment: i would also suggest some OOP reading, its crucial in game dev.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it via [pygame.key.get_pressed()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed):

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if keys[K_LEFT]:
    self.char_x += 10

if keys[K_RIGHT]:
    self.char_x -= 10

if keys[K_UP]:
    self.char_y -= 10

if keys[K_DOWN]:
    self.char_y += 10
```

Comment: i'm afraid this game will run slower on older CPUs

Comment: Should this code be put under the original code or should it replace it?

Comment: @coolbartek: won't most games run slower on older CPUs? What do you mean, specifically?

Comment: Read my answer to find out, you want the character to move at 20px/sec while here you move at 10px/cycle, where cycle speed depends on CPU speed. The game will run slower at slower machines, but the character will move at the same speed. (Less updates, but moves more px/cycle) Is that more clear now?

Comment: Never mind. Thank you so much, BlackBear! I got it to work. :D

Comment: this is great to use multiple keys together, thanks! Two suggestions: 1) call something like "if not any((keys[K_RIGHT],keys[K_LEFT])):" to check if no (e.g.) horizontal move has happened (instead of using events), and 2) call "pygame.event.pump()" after pygame.key.get_pressed() as explained in the function help comments.