# can't make a sprite move diagonally

Tags: python, pygame

I want to move my spaceship sprite with my keyboard diagonally on the screen,but every try has been wrong.I have no problem moving on one direction using the w,s,a,d keys but when i try to combine them ,it just does not work.
for moving in one direction i use the script:

```
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if key[pygame.K_w]:

    classes.Ship.going_right = False
    ship.image = pygame.image.load('Images/myship3.png')
    ship.rect.y -= 8

elif key[pygame.K_s]:

    ship.image = pygame.image.load('Images/myship3.png')
    ship.image = pygame.transform.rotate(ship.image, 180)
    ship.rect.y += 8

elif key[pygame.K_a]:

    ship.image = pygame.image.load('Images/myship3.png')
    ship.image = pygame.transform.rotate(ship.image, 90)
    ship.rect.x -= 8


elif key[pygame.K_d]:

    ship.image = pygame.image.load('Images/myship3.png')
    ship.image = pygame.transform.rotate(ship.image, -90)
    ship.rect.x += 8
```

I had several tries to make the sprite move diagonally up and right(by pressing 'w' and 'd' keys) like:

```
    elif key[pygame.K_w]:
        if key[pygame.K_d]:
            ship.image = pygame.image.load('Images/myship3.png')
            ship.image = pygame.transform.rotate(ship.image, -45)
            ship.rect.x += 8
            ship.rect.y -= 8
```

which does'nt do anything or

```
    elif [key[pygame.K_w] + key[pygame.K_d]]:

    ship.image = pygame.image.load('Images/myship3.png')
    ship.image = pygame.transform.rotate(ship.image, -45)
    ship.rect.x += 8
    ship.rect.y -= 8
```

which moves the ship automatic diagonally up and right(without waiting me to press the keys).I have run out of dumm ideas.Any sugestions?

Comment: IMHO you should check the key events instead of using `pygame.key.get_pressed()`. Check [this](http://pygame.org/docs/tut/chimp/ChimpLineByLine.html) tutorial for more info

Comment: try using a more standard layout concept like the number pad 2,4,6,8 for up/down side to side and 1,3,7,9 for the diagonals

Comment: You may want to check this question: [Programming Pygame so that I can press multiple keys at once to get my character to move diagonally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556535/programming-pygame-so-that-i-can-press-multiple-keys-at-once-to-get-my-character)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are putting the elif after the ifs then it's not going to work. You can change the first if for:

```
if key[pygame.K_w]:
    if key[pygame.K_d]:
        ship.image = pygame.image.load('Images/myship3.png')
        ship.image = pygame.transform.rotate(ship.image, -45)
        ship.rect.x += 8
        ship.rect.y -= 8
    else:
        classes.Ship.going_right = False
        ship.image = pygame.image.load('Images/myship3.png')
        ship.rect.y -= 8
```

Also, I don't know how pygame works, but it seems like a bad idea to read the image file every single time you move the ship. That would be reading a file in the hard drive once per frame. Maybe you should read it once before and keep it in a variable.

Comment: Thanks Mauricio.Your solution worked.Could you please explain what did you mean?How and what to store in a variable?I dont understand

Comment: I meant first loading the image in a variable like `ship3 = pygame.image.load('Images/myship3.png')` before the main loop and then just updating by `ship.image = ship3` when you need to.